# Cannot get 64 bit options to appear in VirtualBox 6.0 (AMD)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit, amd-ryzen

I don't quite see my exact need in the similar questions plus I think I have completed the steps in the posts closer to my environment and I still cannot get the 64bit options to appear.

I have an AMD R5 2600x cpu with the MSI b450 mobo with that one click bios on it (ver 5 I believe).
I have made sure my System Type (Windows 10) says 64 bit OS and x64 based processor.
Secure Virtual Machine is/was enabled by default in the bios.
I turned on Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform in windows features and restarted.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled Virtual Box after each of these steps.

Is there anything else I can do to get 64 bit options to appear in vbox?

Answer (score 1):

So I may have asked too soon because I just got it to work.  Apparently, though the main bios screen said SVM was enabled, it was still disabled.  I had to go to `Advanced` > `Overclocking` > `CPU Features` > `SVM` > `Enable` then `Save`.

Because even though it said it was enabled on the front cpu screen, it really wasn't.